# Flash Grid of images with rollover actions

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

Okay, trying to find a solution to this, I have been searching everywhere. I have a flash project with a grid of images; 3 images tall by 4 images wide. Here's what I want, when you rollover each image, the others get covered up with a larger version of the particular image, no fancy animations or anything like that, it needs to just appear.

The problem I am encountering is that the expanded image is part of the rollover so rolling over anywhere the expanded image should be reveals the larger image. So the million dollar question is... how do I make the only active part of the rollover action be the small version of the image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question, you could place an invisible box that is the required size and add your mouse events to the box rather than the object as a whole. Probably a better solution would to not include the large image in your "thumbnail" but load it on roll over.

Just a word of caution...if I'm reading correctly...what you're describing could cause some bad UI experience. Because rolling over one image covers up all of the other images, once the large image is revealed, the other images below become inaccessible. Say you intend to roll over one image but accidentally roll over an adjacent image. Especially because this is a grid, you start to create a maze for the mouse to access the intended image.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a onenterframe
Event to check for mousex and mousey and see if they are in predefined areas.

Answer (score 0):

Just create buttons that only have 'hit' areas, no actual image/graphics in the other states. Or MovieClips filled with 0% alpha fills that are the size/location of your thumbnails. Don't try to do everything with one object, but use clips with mouse interaction that live above all your image clips. you can use whatever mapping scheme makes sense to you to control the thumbnail/full image actions.

for example (using very short AS3 shorthand ):

name your buttons "b_0", "b_1", etc..

name your image MC's "img_0", "img_1", etc

when you get the rollOver event for the button, get it's instance name ( buttonname = event.currentTarget.name ) and use the String 'split' method to get the identifying number ( id = buttonname.split("_")[1]).

You can then target the correct image MC with 'getChildByName("img_" + id).

The bottom line is that you'll have to use code, cause it's just better and you'll soon be able to do very fun stuff once you get some experience. This is a fun problem, but one you'll want to use AS3 for. There are FAR more elegant solutions that the one I've outlined above, but you've got to start somewhere :)